# when creating a facial recognition app, this error occurs: TypeError: __call__(): incompatible function arguments

Tags: python, face-recognition, face-detection, dlib

error:

```
TypeError: __call__(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: _dlib_pybind11.fhog_object_detector, image: array, upsample_num_times: int=0) -> _dlib_pybind11.rectangles

Invoked with: <_dlib_pybind11.fhog_object_detector object at 0x111932430>, None, 1
```

my code:

```
import cv2
import os
import dlib
import numpy as np
import face_recognition


detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

def compute_face_encoding(image):
   
    face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)
    if len(face_encoding) > 0:
        return face_encoding[0]
    else:
        return None

def compare_face_encodings(face_encoding1, face_encoding2):
    # Compute the Euclidean distance between the face encodings
    distance = np.linalg.norm(face_encoding1 - face_encoding2)

    # Set a threshold value for face matching
    threshold = 0.6  # Adjust this value based on your application's requirements

    # Compare the distance with the threshold
    if distance < threshold:
        return True  # The faces are considered a match
    else:
        return False  # The faces are not a match

def main():
    # Path to the folder containing the reference images
    reference_images_folder = "face_images"

    # Load the reference face encodings
    reference_encodings = []
    reference_image_names = []

    for filename in os.listdir(reference_images_folder):
        # Construct the file path
        file_path = os.path.join(reference_images_folder, filename)

        # Load the reference image
        reference_image = cv2.imread(file_path)

        # Compute the face encoding for the reference image
        reference_encoding = compute_face_encoding(reference_image)
        if reference_encoding is not None:
            reference_encodings.append(reference_encoding)
            reference_image_names.append(filename)

    # Initialize the video capture
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        # Read the current frame from the video capture
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            # End the loop if no frame is available
            break

        # Convert the frame to grayscale
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Detect faces in the grayscale frame
        faces = detector(gray)

        # Iterate over the detected faces
        for face in faces:
            # Predict the facial landmarks for each face
            landmarks = predictor(gray, face)

            # Compute the face encoding for the current frame
            face_encoding = compute_face_encoding(frame)
            if face_encoding is None:
                continue

            # Compare the face encoding with the reference encodings
            for i in range(len(reference_encodings)):
                reference_encoding = reference_encodings[i]
                reference_image_name = reference_image_names[i]

                # Compare the face encodings
                is_match = compare_face_encodings(reference_encoding, face_encoding)

                # Draw a rectangle around the face
                x1, y1 = face.left(), face.top()
                x2, y2 = face.right(), face.bottom()
                color = (0, 255, 0) if is_match else (0, 0, 255)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, 2)

                # Display the name of the matched reference image
                text = reference_image_name if is_match else "Unknown"
                cv2.putText(frame, text, (x1, y1 - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, color, 2)

                # Print whether there is a match or not
                if is_match:
                    print("Match found: Reference Image = {}".format(reference_image_name))

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Real-Time Face Recognition', frame)

        # Check for the 'q' key to exit
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

    # Release the video capture and close the OpenCV windows
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**solutions i've tried:** downgrading or reinstalling dlib or face_recognition but turned out they are not the problems.

**my goal:** is to build an app to recognize my face from live video stream and 10 images of my face is given as reference.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i think that's minimal already since i dont know where is the problem

Comment: complete traceback required. -- file a bug with the `face_recognition` package that you use.

Comment: its very long and idk how to post it here...